# How can i do clickable custom dropdown arrow in css?

Tags: html, css

I set the custom dropdown arrow using css but it is not clickable right know. So how can i fix that?

[image]

```css
.container select{
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 38px 7px 23px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    appearance: none;
    position: relative; 
}
.container i.fa-angle-down{
    position: absolute;
    right: 66.8%;
    top: 92.8%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h6>Current open positions</h6>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="search">Search by Location</label>
    <select>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>Dakor</option>
    </select><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is clickable. Are you sure ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I am asking how can i clickable?

Comment: Your question is not clear to what you wanted apparently. You just wanted to add `pointer when you hover over your select`. that does NOT mean clickable. Glad you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are neater ways of doing what you're trying to achieve. Look up [Select2](https://select2.org/).

In saying this though, the reason your dropdown isn't clickable is because it is overlapping the actual dropdown - to circumvent this, add this property;

`pointer-events: none;` to your `.container i.fa-angle-down` class.

ie;

```
.container i.fa-angle-down{
    position: absolute;
    right: 66.8%;
    top: 92.8%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    pointer-events: none; //enables click-through
}
```

This will enable a "click-through" to the object/element behind it.

Another alternative is [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153080/how-do-i-change-the-select-box-arrow/28274325#28274325) that I found for you, a sample can be found [here](https://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp).

Answer (score 0):

It won't work since you are inserting the font outside of the select which excludes it from the select option. you can use select pseudo-element to achieve the same thing. You can find more about it [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements) on font awesome documentation. does it answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of SVG instead of an extra icon?

```css
.container select{
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 5px 38px 7px 23px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    background-color: Transparent; 
    background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 420 512'><path d='M143 352.3L7 216.3c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l22.6-22.6c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l96.4 96.4 96.4-96.4c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l22.6 22.6c9.4 9.4 9.4 24.6 0 33.9l-136 136c-9.2 9.4-24.4 9.4-33.8 0z' style='fill: rgb(255, 193, 42);'></path></svg>") no-repeat right center;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h6>Current open positions</h6>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="search">Search by Location</label>
    <select>
        <option>Canada</option>
        <option>Dakor</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```