# CSS animation won't work in Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-animations

I have a select box in "multiple" mode that fetch its data asynchronously.
While waiting for the data, I want the select box to show a spinner.
I have the following code working under Chrome, Chromium and Edge but under Firefox (tested on 52 and 57) the box stays plain white.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .multiselect {
      width: 300px;
      height: 200px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .loading:before, .loading:after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      pointer-events: none;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .loading:before {
      width:100%; height:100%;
      background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, .8);
    }
    .loading:after {
      margin: auto;
      width: 32px; height: 32px;
      border: 4px solid #F37324;
      border-left-color: transparent;
      border-top-color: transparent;
      border-radius: 50%;
      animation: spin 600ms infinite linear;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
      from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select class="multiselect loading" multiple></select>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I found a tool (https://www.browseemall.com/Compatibility/ValidateCSS) telling me that this CSS is compatible with FF37.

I tried to add vendor specific rules -moz- to @keyframes, transform and animations and to play with z-index and content but with no success so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem with <select> and :after with CSS in WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit)

Comment: Not sure if it's a duplicate of that question -- the pseudoelement will work in Chrome in his case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` is handled differently between browsers. Pseudoelements are probably best avoided. In your case, the pseudoelement is being applied in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

As an alternative, apply the pseudoelements to a wrapper.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/gfapesz4/2/)

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.loading {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.select-wrapper:before,
.select-wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.select-wrapper:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(211, 211, 211, .8);
}

.select-wrapper:after {
  margin: auto;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 4px solid #F37324;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 600ms infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <select class="multiselect loading" multiple></select>
</div>
```

Comment: the loading class should be moved to .select-wrapper, too. As the class is an indicator of loading and animation is binded to the wrapper

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the animation. It is because of using pseudo-elements in select.

It is not good practice to use after and before pseudo-elements in select. You should add a wrapper div and style that div.

[problem with <select> and :after with CSS in WebKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit)

Comment: it's better to flag as duplicate if you find a similar question

Comment: the question I posted is a proof of what I am telling - not an answer. He thinks that the problem is in animation.