# I want to show the arrow in my selected box to rotate 180 deg, when I click

Tags: jquery, html, css

```css
select:required:invalid {
  color: gray !important;
}
option[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
option {
  color: black;
}

.form-select-cutom {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.form-select-custom:before {
  content: ""url(../images/arrow-down-sign-to-navigate.png)"";
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group form-select-custom">
  <select class="form-control" id="select1">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Salutation</option>
    <option>Mr</option>
    <option>Mrs</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want to rotate the arrow 180 deg when I click on the select box and again rotate back when I click for the second time.I tried with jquery and also with css. It's not working perfectly. Can some one please help me with this issue. Thank You.

Comment: You cannot use pseudo elements on select elements. Check out this answer for a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25574218/1172189

Comment: @disinfor the pseudo element isn't on the select

Comment: @temani afif what do I do, to make it rotate.

Comment: You will need some JS here, listen to the click event and adjust the css based on that

Comment: @TemaniAfif yep! In my haste I read the markup wrong :X