# Why DOM-element <select> can't have :before or :after?

Tags: html, css

I knew why inputs doesnt have it (except in Google Chrome), but why selects does not have it, when they have end tag?

Comment: that duplicate doesn't answer the *why*

Comment: "The select tags doesn't allow :after or :before pseudos because they are customized by each vendor, so it's quite hard to modify them and that's because they don't allow :before or :after pseudo elements on them."? Also explains why in [Problem with select in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit)

Comment: @KarlChelton that answer starts by *Well, it looks like the ..* everyone can notice this behavior while trying to customize the select which is a clear fact thus the question of *why* it's like that? Where it's defined to be like? is it something official described in the specification?

Answer (score -1):

They are customizable and therefore hard to handle with `:before` or `:after`.

You can try wrapping it with a div maybe.