# Add padding to the right of select drop down arrow (chrome)

Tags: css, google-chrome

The client would like rounded corners on the select box, however now the drop down arrow is very close to the edge. How does one add some padding. It pretty much only has to support chrome.

I thought of making the right border radii zero, then use ::after to add some extra background with the radius. However I [can't use `select::after`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532649/problem-with-select-and-after-with-css-in-webkit), since Chrome does not support that.

And [chrome does not have any pseduo elements](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_date) from styling the select.

So I think it's not possible, but is worth asking here if anyone knows some clever tricks, that do not use background url images, since due to security issues I cant apply them.

Heres an example where you can see how close the dropdown arrow is to the edge:

[image]

```css
select {
  background: #444;
  color:white;
  border-radius:16px;
  height:32px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="1">The one and only</option>
</select>
```

Comment: simply; using `border: 8px solid #444;` to expand the area instead of padding might help you.

Comment: @Hello, that is a brillant idea, I can only go 4px before it doesnt fit anymore, but the 4px is enough to not look too bad, so its a pass! Thank you. I would accept this as an answer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an image icon like the below code:

```
:root::-webkit-media-controls-panel,
select {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    background-image: url(down-arrow.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 15px center;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Also, You add a class before the "select" tag.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but guessing you missed the "not use background url images, since due to security issues I cant apply them" part.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code, I am sure your issue will be resolved.

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
    
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
    l = x.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      ll = selElmnt.length;
    
      a = document.createElement("DIV");
      a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
      a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
      x[i].appendChild(a);
    
      b = document.createElement("DIV");
      b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
      for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
        /*for each option in the original select element,
        create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
        c = document.createElement("DIV");
        c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
        c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
            var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
            s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            sl = s.length;
            h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
            for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
              if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                s.selectedIndex = i;
                h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                yl = y.length;
                for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
                  y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                }
                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                break;
              }
            }
            h.click();
        });
        b.appendChild(c);
      }
      x[i].appendChild(b);
      a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    
          e.stopPropagation();
          closeAllSelect(this);
          this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
          this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
        });
    }
    function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
    
      var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
      x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
      y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
      xl = x.length;
      yl = y.length;
      for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
        if (elmnt == y[i]) {
          arrNo.push(i)
        } else {
          y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
        }
      }
      for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
        if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
          x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
        }
      }
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
 .custom-select {
          position: relative;
          font-family: Arial;
        }
        
        .custom-select select {
          display: none; /*hide original SELECT element:*/
        }
        
        .select-selected {
          background-color: DodgerBlue;
        }
        
        
        .select-selected:after {
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          top: 14px;
          right: 10px;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border: 6px solid transparent;
          border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
        }
        
        
        .select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
          border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
          top: 7px;
        }
        
        .select-items div,.select-selected {
          color: #ffffff;
          padding: 8px 16px;
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
          cursor: pointer;
          user-select: none;
        }
        
        
        .select-items {
          position: absolute;
          background-color: DodgerBlue;
          top: 100%;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
          z-index: 99;
        }
        
        .select-hide {
          display: none;
        }
        
        .select-items div:hover, .same-as-selected {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
```

```html
<div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
      <select>
        <option value="0">Select car:</option>
        <option value="1">Audi</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
        <option value="3">Citroen</option>
        <option value="4">Ford</option>
        <option value="5">Honda</option>
        <option value="6">Jaguar</option>
        <option value="7">Land Rover</option>
        <option value="8">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="9">Mini</option>
        <option value="10">Nissan</option>
        <option value="11">Toyota</option>
        <option value="12">Volvo</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```